# I wanna write code that creates different number of entry widgets depending on user input?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a code that creates a tournament bracket after the user inputs a list of players/teams. I want to create entry widgets for the user to type in the names of each player/team. However, since the number of players/teams participating in a particular tournament depends on the user, I want to write a code where a user inputs the number of players/teams in one entry widget which causes that number of new entry widgets to pop up for the user to input the names of each player/team.

I have written the following code but it shows an error: Entry.get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

```
def enter_items1():
enter_teams1_screen = Tk()
enter_teams1_screen.geometry("1000x500")
enter_teams1_screen.title("Enter Players/Teams")
What_User_Wrote = Entry.get()
Convert_To_Int = int(What_User_Wrote)
Convert_To_Int = int(Entry.get())
widgets = []
for ent in range (Convert_To_Int()):
    ent = tk.Entry(root)
    ent.pack()
    widgets.append(ent)
```

How do I remove this error and write the code I am looking for.

Comment: This will be a multistep process.  You need to create the entry widgets, and you need to create a "Finished" button.  Then, this function is finished.  Nothing else will happen until the user clicks "Finished".  In the "Finished" handler, that's where you will fetch the values from those entry widgets.

Comment: You didn't provide how you import tkinter, or if you ever assign to `Entry`, but I assume `Entry.get()` calls it on tbe class, not a specific instance. Thus your error.

Answer (score 2):

I understood as by input data the no of entries wiz should be created, I think the following code will be useful,

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
num_of_teams = StringVar()

entries = []


def generateTeams():
    for i in range(int(num_of_teams.get())):
        entries.append(Entry(root, font="Helvetica 10",))
        entries[i].pack(expand=TRUE, fill='both', padx=5, pady=5)


Label(root, text="Enter NO of Teams:").pack()
Entry(root, textvariable=num_of_teams).pack()
Button(root, text="Generate Tables", command=generateTeams).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

the no of entry will be created by input data